# Should pairing questions on Homebrew.SE be migrated here?

Tags: discussion, migration

The Homebrew.SE site has a few questions about food pairings:

https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pairing

Should these be migrated to Beer.SE?

Answer (score 5):

Not right now. We're too early in the beta process for incoming migrations, for two reasons. The first is that our survival is tenuous right now. The second is that as a new beta we don't want an influx of migrations that will change or set the tone of the site.

When we get on our feet a little bit better (a few months in perhaps, after we have an established tone and userbase), if y'all decide that those are off topic on your site, then yeah, send them over, so far they're on topic here (that could change though).

Lastly, as far as your existing questions, most likely unless SE wants to do a bulk transfer, they are probably mostly too old for migration (60 days).